# What happens when android app is "killed"

Tags: android

I have an app which has real time push notifications enabled. So my query is whenever any user tries to **kill** my app using "Advance Task Killer", my app goes into undefined state.

**Undefined State**: What i mean is my app doesn't gets completely terminated. The screen has data in a inconsistent state.

So is there way where i can take a user to login screen back whenever an app is killed. So that user wont see any undefined state.

Also want to know what happens to my app states after it gets killed so that i can fix the issue.

Help Appreciated.

Comment: What happens when android app is "killed"? It "die".

Comment: Are you using remote processes? In other words, do you have any `Service` instances in your AndroidManifest.xml marked with the `android:process=":remote"` option?

Comment: @femi no i don't have android:process attribute in my manifest

Answer (score 4):

It depends on the version of the platform.  Prior to 2.2, third party applications like ATK could use an API that did the same thing as the "Force Stop" button in manage apps -- this kills all app processes, removes all tasks/activities, unregisters all alarms, removes all notifications, stops all services, etc.  Basically make the application not running the same as if it was first installed, except its persistent data is still intact.

Needless to say, this tends to cause misbehavior of applications, so as of 2.2 other applications like ATK can no longer do this to your app.  The API they were using is now only able to do the same thing that the out of memory killer does -- kill the application processes but only if they are in the background in a killable state.  It can do *no more* than the normal out of memory killer, so as of 2.2 if your application is misbehaving due to an app like ATK being used on it then this is exposing an actual bug in the app that users will encounter through the normal use of their device.

Comment: My app minSdk is 7 and the ATK version is v1.9.6 build 76 and yes its killing the app, because whenever my app is killed from ATK its clearing all my cache data thats causing the undefined state of my app but with "Force Stop" button in manage apps my app takes the user back to login screen which is the expected behavior. So is it ATK bug or do i have to handle on my side?

Comment: It's not killing the app, it is killing the process.  The system will do this when it needs memory.  You need to deal with your process being killed when it is in the background.  See here for an overview of the states a process can be in and when it can be killed: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/fundamentals/processes-and-threads.html#Lifecycle